# closing html tags in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

I'm having problems when receive a meta which is html code. That is:

```
...
echo $metas["temario"];
...
```

Where $metas["temario"] is i.e:

```
<p><span style="border:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:baseline"><strong>TEMA I&nbsp;</strong><span style="border:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:baseline">&nbsp;<span style="border:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:baseline"><strong>La Respiraci&oacute;n</strong></span></span></span></p> <p><span style="border:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:baseline"><strong>TEMA II</strong></span>&nbsp;<span style="border:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:baseline"><span style="border:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:baseline">&nbsp;<strong><span style="border:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:baseline">La Importancia de la Respiraci&oacute;n</span></strong></span></span></p> <p><strong><span style="border:0px;
```

And I need close this html when I receive it incorrectly, because then it affects to next divs incorrectly...

Is there any function for this?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you looking for, but you can probably make your own function. When the data returns "incorrectly" return some ending tags from your function.

Comment: How are you saying your meta `temario` ? By Default WordPress doesn't add any HTML to post meta data.

Answer (score 0):

You may switch the double marks to single. Try using ' instead " and check on the function file how the loop are generating this code.